# Jquery focus() with checkboxes problem

Tags: jquery, input, checkbox, onfocus

We use a custom jquery plugin to handle our help pop-ups when users focus on input fields. However I've stumbled upon an odd problem. The plugin uses the following code to trigger the help popup:

```
$(this).focus(function(){
    // Show popup help panel here
});
```

However, if this code is applied to an input where type="checkbox", the help popup is displayed, but the checkbox value quickly negates itself, therefore appearing not to have changed from ticked to unticked or vice-versa. This happens in IE9 and FF6 (not tried it in other browsers). I tried this very simple code just to make sure I wasn't going insane, and the issue still occurred:

... In html:

```
<input id="test" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
```

... In head - javascript

```
$('#test').focus(function(){
    alert("help!");
});
```

The alert is displayed, but the checkbox value isn't changed (or was changed but then changed back, as I think is happening).

Can anyone shed any light on this.

Comment: Does it help if you check or uncheck the checkbox in the method itself?

Comment: Hi Baszz, thanks for the constructive comment - that work-around does work, however I'm none the wiser as to why this is happening. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Why bind on 'focus' for a checkbox?

That doesn't make much sense to me as 'focus' is primarily for textboxes or textareas.  I'd use `.click` or `.change` instead, I'd suspect you'll have better luck.

Did some testing on a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/65CRb/1) and binding `focus` doesn't even work at all in Chrome.  I'd suspect there's some weird eventing going on in IE/FF that isn't propagating to the actual control itself when you focus.

Comment: I would try click. focus may have issues with the checkbox. the event may happen before the check/tick is rendered. May cause it to double click, look like it is negating it self.

Comment: @Adam - that's what I thought initially, however there is a scenario where the user is using the tab key to change focus, in which case the checkbox IS focussed, but it's value should not be changed. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: So... I ask again, why use focus?  You want to take action when they use the tab key to highlight it but not when they click on it?  Or on both, but you also want the click to work?  "Focus" functionality on a checkbox is simply not a good design decision.  I strongly recommend taking a different approach to whatever made you think you need to do that.  Like I said before, it's wholly unsupported in Chrome, and likely Safari as well.

Comment: Well, I just used chrome to focus on a checkbox with the tab key, then check it by pressing space, so it's quite the opposite of 'wholly unsupported'. I would just expect some consistency with regards to focussing and clicking in inputs, be they text, checkboxes, or whatever.

Comment: I didn't say that you couldn't focus on the element, I said that clicking on it doesn't fire the focus event.

Comment: I have run into a similar problem. I notice that tabbing to the check boxes does trigger the focus, but as @AdamTerlson mentioned, clicking does not have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

`focus` will not change the `checked` property of checkbox. You have to explicity change its checked property. Something like this.

```
$('#test').focus(function(){
    this.checked = !this.checked;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, i'm well aware of that, but it's not the issue. The issue is that when the user clicks on the checkbox, it receives focus and SHOULD have it's value toggled, however the latter isn't happening.

Comment: which you click on a checkbox focus event triggers first but by that time the the checkbox is not yet triggered so you dont get the toggled value. Checkbox checks/unchecks after the focus event is triggered.